# How to create separate class instance with default arguments in __init__

Tags: python, function, class, arguments, parameter-passing

The class definition:

```
class tr():
  def __init__(self,l=[]):
    self.l = l
  def added(self):
    self.l.append(1)
```

```
colt1 = tr()
colt1.added()
print(colt1.l)
```

Output is
**[1]**
Executed the below code after the above one

```
colt2 = tr()
colt2.added()
print(colt2.l)
```

Output is
**[1, 1]**

I would like to have the output for the second segment also to be **[1]** with the class getting the data members from the **init** function and also having a default argument.
So how should I alter the code to get this output?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Oh! This page has answered the question, But I was unable to locate it, Should be because of the fancy title!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard thing to do is have this sort of thing for your `__init__` method:

```py
    def __init__(self, l=None):
        if l is None:
            l = []
        self.l = l
```

You can check out this FAQ entry: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects